# Store chars in matrix from txt file

Tags: c

i want to store that matrix that i have in txt file in my matrix array and i wanted to print it just to know that is correctly stores, but when i print the program just print half of it.

Basically, after i run the problem it print this:

```
X . . X
. O
```

I don't know why is printing half of it, here is my code:

my tabuleiro.txt is:

```
3 4
X . . X
. O . X
. . O .
```

where that two numbers are the size of the matrix.

*

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char matrix[100][100];
    int lines=0,columns=0,i=0,j=0,l=0,c=0;
    fp = fopen("tabuleiro.txt","r");
    fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&lines,&columns);
    for(i=1;i<=lines;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=columns;j++){
            fscanf(fp,"%c",&matrix[i][j]);
            printf("%c", matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

*

Comment: `"%c"` doesn't skip the spaces or newline characters in the input file. To skip whitespace, use `" %c"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In above program, the whitespace between array elements in `tabuleiro.txt` is not being read. Space read only while reading first row in

```
fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&lines,&columns);
```

Modifying the nested `for` loops, with an additional declaration before, as follows:

```
    char whitespace;
    for(i=1;i<=lines;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=columns;j++){
            fscanf(fp, "%c", &matrix[i][j]);
            fscanf(fp, "%c", &whitespace);
            printf("%c", matrix[i][j]);
            printf("%c", whitespace);
        }
    }
```

prints the required result

```
X . . X
. O . X
. . O .
```